# how to pass created token in 2nd thread group

Tags: jmeter

How To pass token in 2nd thread group.

I have tried adding json extractor in 1st thread group and then added beanshell preprocessor in 2nd thread group

I am getting invalid token

Answer (score 0):

1. Since JMeter 3.1 you should be using [JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting).
2. You need to convert the [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) holding your token into a JMeter Property, for this add a [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) after the JSON Extractor and put the following code to "Script" area:

   ```
   props.put('token', vars.get('variable-holding-your-token'))
   ```
3. In 2nd Thread Group you can use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) for accessing the token like:

   ```
   ${__P(token,)}
   ```

More information: [Using JMeter Variables With Multiple Thread Groups](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-variables)